# How to merge two PHP cURL code into one cURL

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, mime-types, file-get-contents

I am using cURL to get string and content type from external website. For now i am using two cURL function. The problem is it requesting two time to same web page for string and content type.

**Content Type :**

```
function get_content_type_curl($url_content_type) {
    
    $agent_content_type = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch_content_type = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_URL, $url_content_type);
    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent_content_type);
    curl_setopt($ch_content_type, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_exec($ch_content_type);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch_content_type, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    curl_close($ch_content_type);

    return $content_type;
}

$content_type = get_content_type_curl("https://example.com");

header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);
```

**String :**

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
echo $homepage;
```

How to make it request one time to `example.com` and get both `string` and `content_type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return the array from one of the curl method having both content type and the data.

```
    function get_curl($url_content_type)
    {
        $agent_curl = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_content_type);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent_curl);

        $data         = curl_exec($ch);
        $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

        curl_close($ch);

        return compact('data', 'content_type');
    }

    $data = get_curl("https://example.com");
    $homepage     = $data['data'];
    $content_type = $data['content_type'];

    header('Content-Type:'.$content_type);
    echo $homepage;
```

Comment: add/update curl options as per your need

Comment: This will make two HTTP requests

Comment: no this will not make 2 HTTP requests. It will make a single request. You already have both required data in the single request. Unless you call the `get_curl` method twice it will just make 1 curl request.

Comment: I have modified your code as per my need. can you check if it is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75535208/20776947

Comment: I tested your code. it giving blank output.

Comment: @MehulKumar strange, what do you get from ```$data = get_curl("https://example.com");var_dump($data);die();``` ?

Comment: @MehulKumar updated the curl options to get the HTML content. check it.

Comment: @AnujShrestha it works. But how it getting `content-type` when we set `Header` to `0` in curl?

Comment: @MehulKumar then ask *ChatGPT* to write the code for you!!! Also, ChatGPT is temporarily banned from StackOverflow. Also, you know how to actually test if it makes 2 calls or not right or actually understand what the above code is doing? Or do you take ChatGPT's response as 100% true and make it write code for you? You can remove the `CURLOPT_HEADER` from there,

Comment: @AnujShrestha i have no idea how to check how many HTTP request has been made. So, as a alternative i used that bot to check your code. I know it provide lot of false report. So, removing `CURLOPT_HEADER` will not have any affect on code and it will still provide the same result.

Comment: @AnujShrestha can you help me. How to find no of HTTP request made by cURL? incase i have to find and show that to my client?

Answer (score 1):

To merge two cURL with one HTTP Request

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    // Get the content type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    // Get the content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Set the content type header
    header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);

    return $data;
}

$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
```

Comment: this is not a good solution, you're still doing 2x http requests when 1 request suffice. see Anju's post above.

Comment: @hanshenrik How to find no of http request made with cURL to URL?